# How do I load an Image from $templateCache using Angular 1

Tags: angularjs, angular-templatecache

I have a [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/AmMUdczARUm3QJbz7UME) and the story is long but it comes down to I need to be able to use an image from the templateCache. I try to do this using ng-src like this...

```
$templateCache.put('img/help/copy_icon', '://www.drupal.org/files/issues/sample_7.png')
...
template: '<img ng-src="{{url}}">'
```

However this doesn't work and I get...

> copy_icon':1 GET https://run.plnkr.co/ZyTH7LFhPLhdQpCI/'img/help/copy_icon' 400 ()

So it isn't trying to get it from templateCache. Is there a way to do this?

**Update**

I tried ...

```
$http.get('://www.drupal.org/files/issues/sample_7.png').success(function (t) {
  $templateCache.put('img/help/copy_icon', t);
});
```

But that didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I do not know exactly what you try to achieve by using $templateCache, which in your case just saves image URL to the cache, but I modified your code a bit, so it displays an image, I added controller:

```
app.run(function($templateCache){
  $templateCache.put('img/help/copy_icon', 'http://www.drupal.org/files/issues/sample_7.png')
})

app.directive('ngImg', function(){
  return {
    rectrict: "E",
    scope: {
      url: "@url"
    },
    template: '<img ng-src="{{ imgUrl }}">',
    controller: function ($scope, $templateCache) {
      $scope.imgUrl = $templateCache.get($scope.url);
    }
  }
})
```

plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/q5a9ptq8rd1G4uGkkNMe?p=preview

BTW, using *ng* prefix for custom directives names is not recommended and should be reserved for angular core directives/components

Comment: "BTW, using ng prefix for custom directives names is not recommended and should be reserved for angular core directives/components" -- touche

Thank for being one of the few that cares. This was just for example purposes. The explanation is extensive and based on many bad decisions. Let me test this and get back to you.